# Logistic function passing through two points?

Tags: statistics

**Quick formulation of the problem:**
Given two points: $(x_l, y_l)$ and $(x_u, y_u)$
with: $x_l < x_u$ and $y_l < y_u$,
and given lower asymptote=0 and higher asymptote=1,
what's the logistic function that passes through the two points?

**Explanatory image:**
[image: logistic]

**Other details:**
I'm given two points in the form of Pareto 90/10 (green in the example above) or 80/20 (blue in the example above), and I know that the upper bound is one and the lower bound is zero.

How do I get the formula of a sigmoid function (such as the logistic function) that has a lower asymptote on the left and higher asymptote on the right and passes via the two points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're looking for constants $a$ and $b$ so that $f(x_\ell) = y_\ell$ and $f(x_u) = y_u$ where $f(x) = \exp(a + bx) / (1 + \exp(a + bx))$.

This is equivalent to the linear system $a + b x_\ell = g(y_\ell)$ and $a + b x_u = g(y_u)$ where $g(y) = f^{-1}(y) = \log(y/(1-y))$.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8214/105986), if we have a logistic function using the common notation:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$

... and we want to solve for $k$ and $x_0$ given two points, $(x_l, y_l)$ and $(x_u, y_u)$:

First we can group the unknowns in a single term $b \equiv k(x-x_0)$.  So:

$$y = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-b}}$$
$$y(1 + e^{-b}) = 1$$
$$e^{-b} = \frac{1-y}{y}$$
$$-b = \ln\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)$$
$$ b = \ln\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)$$

Now we expand *b*:
$$k(x-x_0) = \ln\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)$$

... which gives us a linear system to solve for $k$ and $x_0$ given the values of two $(x, y)$ coordinates.