# Logistic function passing through two points AND the origin?

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

I had recently asked the question:
[Logistic function passing through two points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8213/2916)
which received a very helpful answer. However, I'd like to ask your help again as the formulation of the problem has slightly changed and i'm lost...

**Problem:**
Given two points: $(x_l, y_l)$ and $(x_u, y_u)$
with: $x_l < x_u$ and $y_l < y_u$,
and given that the higher asymptote is one ($\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1$)
what's the logistic function that passes through the two points **and the origin $(0, 0)$**?

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirements for the function to pass through the origin and for it to be asymptotic to $y=0$ are incompatible. Think hard on why.

Comment: You are right. Even removing that meaningless constraint (and having lower asymptote somewhere < 0), I've no idea how to make it work... Any help?

Comment: You might want to edit your question. So, to clarify and shorten: it has to pass through the origin, and $y=1$ must be an asymptote?

Comment: Correct. And obviously, pass through the two points. I'll now edit the question.

Comment: So, it should pass through *three* points? Note that the logistic function as shown in John's answer to your previous question has only *two* parameters...

Comment: Yes, through the three points. That's why I'm stuck...

Comment: John's answer has two parameters because it implicitly assumes the asymptotes $y=0$ and $y=1$, so you can't just throw out the $y=0$ constraint without changing the form of the function. So you really need to say more about what kind of a function you want.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it is __still__ a logistic function. Just it passes through the origin and two other points, and it has higher asymptote y=1.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist on $y=0$ as lower asymptote, but instead want the graph to pass through $(0,0)$, the general form of logistic function becomes 
$$y=1-\frac{b}{1+b\,e^{ax}}$$ where $a,b$ are determined from the two given points, and $b>0$. It's easy to eliminate $b$ from one of two equations:
$$b=  \frac{1-y_\ell}{1+(y_\ell-1)e^{ax_\ell}}$$
 but plugging this into the second to find $a$, we get  something that calls for numeric solution.

Comment: Your first equation cannot pass through the origin. $x = 0$ gives $y = 1 - \dfrac{b}{1+b}$