# sigmoid/logistic function passing through the origin

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

I am using a logistic function to model observed response values (growth) as function of an input value:

$$\text{growth} = \displaystyle{\frac{A}{1+e^{\frac{k-\text{input}}{s}}}}$$

This functional form has lower asymptote of growth=$0$, but at input=$0$ it can assume a positive growth value.

I would like to use a similar sigmoid function with the constraint of growth=$0$ at input=$0$.

How can I modify the function?

I found this but it did not solve the problem: [Logistic function passing through two points AND the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/logistic-function-passing-through-two-points-and-the-origin)

Comment: This is not possible. To have $\mathrm{growth} = 0$, you need the denominator to be $+\infty$ (or $A = 0$ but in that case, $\mathrm{growth}$ is identically zero). This happens when $\mathrm{input} \to -\infty$ (if $s > 0$).

Comment: thanks. is there any different sigmoid function that can be constrained to pass through the origin?

Comment: If the sigmoid function is given by:

$$ s(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)} $$

then:

$$ \tilde{s}(x) = s(x) - \frac{1}{2} $$

goes through the origin at $x=0$. $\tilde{s}$ is a translated sigmoid function.